# Styling ticks in a plot

Tags: plotting, ticks

I managed to turn the ticks inside-out but the ticks go now through the numbers. In fact I would like to have it like in the picture attached (ticks pointing outside the plot and no additional ticks between the numbers). Has anyone a suggestion?

```
data={-1.2056,-(7288960271654/4985881289361),-1.30053,-(33199059446612625/13128459048331036),-(5130109517723890585/5148852459134416857),-1.73904,-1.164,-1.83398,-0.97505,-(152151059187768664247/302333262014074402254),-(33596749386427335752225/52657796909983176600514),-0.785963,-0.398132,-(2414923435622638997136189344226575/3392598745831412249336953513454508),-0.820439};
a=First[HistogramList[data]]
b=Range[Max[Last[HistogramList[data]]]]
Histogram[
  data,
  BarOrigin->Left,
  Axes->False,
  Frame->{{True,None},{True,None}},
  FrameTicks->{
              {Transpose[{a,a,Table[{-0.02,0},{i,Length[a]}]}],None},
              {Transpose[{b,b,Table[{-0.02,0},{i,b}]}],None}
              }
]
```

[image: Example]

Comment: In future, please avoid the use of `%n` in the code you post here. A good number of folks use a `$HistoryLength` different from the default and you can't guarantee `%%%` works for all :)

Comment: @R.M out of curiosity, why do you change `$HistoryLength` and what does it do? (Or am I opening a big can of worms, and should actually post the question :)?)

Comment: @tkott it changes the number of saved output expression that *Mathematica* keeps.  When working with large expressions setting `$HistoryLength = 0` can save a lot of memory.  I personally use `3`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works, but it does require some manual tweaking

```
Histogram[data, BarOrigin -> Left, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Transpose[{a, 
      Row[{#, Pane["", {10, Automatic}]}] & /@ a, 
      Table[{-0.02, 0}, {i, Length[a]}]}], 
    None}, {Transpose[{b, 
      Pane[#, {Automatic, 20}, Alignment -> {Center, Bottom}] & /@ b, 
      Table[{-0.02, 0}, {i, b}]}], None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: huh, and I thought the way I answered was hacky. If @Heike does it similarly, then I guess I'm doing OK

Comment: @tkott you are definitely doing OK. You have given some nice answers recently.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit 3**

Looking at the other solutions, I noticed that they all have more or less cumbersome ways of addressing the spacing problem of the labels. I think this particular aspect is more robustly addressed using `Framed` as I did in the original solution below (where I focused on using *LevelScheme*). Here is what a bare-bones solution without additional packages would look like:

```
Histogram[data, BarOrigin -> Left, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}, FrameTicks -> Map[
   {Transpose[{#, 
       Framed[#, FrameStyle -> None, 
          FrameMargins -> 10] & /@ #, {-0.02, 0} & /@ #}], 
     None} &, {a, b}]]
```

**LevelScheme based solution:**

If you do this kind of thing often, it may be worth starting over and doing your plots with the *CustomTicks* package by Mark Caprio. The [web page](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/) has the package as a zip file (the main package is called *LevelScheme*). There is a separate user guide for *CustomTicks* near the bottom of that page. For example, there is an option called `ShowMinorTicks` that can be set to `False`. You can still use "in" and "out" lengths for the tick marks to get them to point out of the frame as in your example.

**Edit**

Here is a version of the original histogram code using *CustomTicks*:

```
Histogram[data, BarOrigin -> Left, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {
  {LinTicks[-3, 0, 1, 1, MajorTickLength -> {0, .02}], 
    None}, 
  {LinTicks[0, 8, ShowMinorTicks -> False, 
    MajorTickLength -> {0, .02}, 
     TickLabelFunction -> (Framed[#2, FrameStyle -> None] &)], 
    None}
 }]
```

In the extremely useful convenience function `TickLabelFunction` provided by the package, I used `Framed` without frame to create more space for the labels. The output looks like this:

[image: histogram with CustomTicks]

A final word about installing the package on Mac OS X: you have to follow the instructions in the LevelScheme guide, and *avoid* installing into the standard location `/Library/Mathematica/Applications/`! This is a little weird, but if you install into any other directory (e.g., in your home directory), the package should load fine. I remember this having been that way for years, but it's just a minor hiccup in an otherwise very useful package.

**Edit 2**
**Updated**

If you simply drag the `LevelScheme` folder into *Mathematica*'s `Applications` folder on Mac OS X, the package will not be loadable (as of version 3.52). You'll get the error

> Get::noopen: Cannot open LevelScheme`. >>

A more streamlined installation process on Mac OS X requires modifying the `init.m` file in the downloaded distribution. Instead of describing this in words, I've written an "installer" function that should be able to set up *LevelScheme* for you (only for Mac OS X):

```
installLevelScheme[downloadDirectory_] := 
 Module[{initPath, initContents,
   initFile = FileNameJoin[{"LevelScheme", "init.m"}], 
   targetDir = 
    FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "LevelScheme"}]},
  initPath = FileNameJoin[{targetDir, "Kernel"}];
  Check[SetDirectory[downloadDirectory];
   initContents = Import[initFile, "Text"];
   Print[initContents];
   DeleteFile[initFile], 
   Return["Unzip the downloaded file (again) and enter the name of the resulting folder!"]];
  Check[CopyDirectory[
    FileNameJoin[{downloadDirectory, "LevelScheme"}], targetDir], 
   Return["Installation directory already exists and hasn't been modified"]];
  Check[CreateDirectory[initPath], 
   Return["Initialization directory already exists and hasn't been modified"]];
  Export[FileNameJoin[{initPath, "init.m"}], 
   "AppendTo[$Path,\"/Library/Mathematica/Applications/LevelScheme\"];\n" <> 
    initContents, "Text"];]
```

Now all you have to do is download *LevelScheme* from the [web page](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/) linked above and unzip it to find a folder called `~/Downloads/LevelScheme` (in my case). Make sure that the directory `/Library/Mathematica/Applications/LevelScheme` doesn't exist yet, and then call the above function like this:

```
installLevelScheme["~/Downloads/LevelScheme"]
```

Now you should restart Mathematica. To load the package, it is from now on sufficient to just type the standard command

```
Needs["LevelScheme`"]
```

Comment: I followed the instructions, still I have troubles to install LevelScheme:

`AppendTo[$Path, 
  "/Users/me/Documents/MyPaper/Mathematica/LevelScheme"];
Get["LevelScheme`"]`

The output was `$Failed`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @John To verify that you're pointing to the right place, check that `SetDirectory["/Users/me/Documents/MyPaper/Mathematica/LevelScheme"];FileNames[]` yields the output `{"BlockOptions", "ClipToRectangle", "CustomTicks", "doc", "ForEach", "InheritOptions", "LevelScheme", "NamedColors"}`. If not, you may be too deep or too shallow in the folder hierarchy of the package. Let me know what you see.

Comment: It's really annoying when package authors use nonstandard installation/load schemes such as with $LevelScheme$. You $can$ put the directory in `/Library/Mathematica/Applications` or in your user base directory: inside `LevelScheme` make subdirectory `Kernel` then put there file `init.m` from `LevelScheme/LevelScheme/` and edit the file by inserting the appropriate `AppendTo[$Path,...];` expression.

Comment: It's also awkward that $LevelScheme$ uses some `.pdf`s and some example notebooks for documentation rather than the current Documentation Center paradigm. But we should still be thankful for the application's author making this available at all.

Comment: @murray Thanks for these observations! The init.m modification you suggested does indeed work, and streamlines the loading process a lot. I'll try to think of a way to add these instructions to my answer.

Comment: @Jens: There are a whole bunch of add-ons out there that have similar problems -- often just a `.m` package and a doc file, perhaps a `.nb` and perhaps a source `.nb` notebook. Merely in order to streamline the top-level `Appplications` folder of my `$UserBaseDirectory`, I now always use the `Kernel/init.m` maneuver.

Comment: @Jens: re your edit, about to your answer: ooh! With a function to modify the way this one particular application is installed, on one platform, what should come next is obviously a package for installing any non-standard-install package and on any platform.

Comment: @murray And what about an installer for that package?

Comment: I have it installed in `Applications` and it seems to work fine.  I'm on Windows though.  What goes wrong if you install into `Applications`?

Comment: @Szabolcs I just checked by removing the `init.m` file created in this answer, and edited the post to include the error message I got. Hopefully that will help people find this fix if they search for the error. So `Applications` works on Windows, but on Mac it only works with the fix @murray gave above.

Comment: I wish I'd seen this earlier... I just installed the package and went through all the `init.m`s and (manually) added an extra `LevelScheme\``. Could you consider posting this as an answer to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28268/cant-load-levelscheme-package). For the record, copy-pasting the subfolders directly to the "Applications" folder also works without the need to place LevelScheme's `init.m` inside a "Kernel" folder

Answer (score 4):

Here is a variant of Heike's answer using `AdjustmentBox`. The `DisplayForm` element is essential for it to show properly.

```
Histogram[data, BarOrigin -> Left, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Transpose[{a, DisplayForm@AdjustmentBox[#, 
                   BoxBaselineShift -> 0, 
          BoxMargins -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}] & /@ a, 
      Table[{-0.02, 0}, {i, Length[a]}]}], 
    None}, {Transpose[{b, DisplayForm@AdjustmentBox[#, 
                   BoxBaselineShift -> 0, 
          BoxMargins -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}] & /@ b, 
      Table[{-0.02, 0}, {i, b}]}], None}}]
```

The `AdjustmentBox` approach is a bit more flexible if you want to move the labels with a lot of control, as shown in this example with the x-axis labels tucked up next to the `FrameTicks`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a really (really) hacky way of doing this, and I hope someone has come up with a better answer while I was looking at this.

```
Histogram[data, BarOrigin -> Left, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Transpose[{a, 
      StringJoin[#, "   "] & /@ (ToString /@ a), 
      Table[{-0.02, 0}, {i, Length[a]}]}], 
    None}, {Transpose[{b, StringJoin["\r", #] & /@ (ToString /@ b), 
      Table[{-0.02, 0}, {i, b}]}], None}}]
```

Resulting in

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Another hack: Use the `Style` option to create an invisible tickmark that extends in both sides of the axis and prepend the tick list with it. You can control the placement of the labels playing with the two parameters of the invisible tick.

Using  `data`, `a` and `b` defined in OP's question,

```
 Histogram[data, BarOrigin -> Left, Axes -> False,  
 Frame -> {{True, True}, {True,   True}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Prepend[
 Transpose[{a, a, Table[{-0.02, 0}, {i, Length[a]}]}], 
 {a[[1]], "", {-0.02, .02}, Opacity[0]}], 
 Prepend[Transpose[{a, a, Table[{-0.02, 0}, {i, Length[a]}]}], 
 {a[[1]], "", {-0.05, .05}, Opacity[0]}]}, 
 {Prepend[Transpose[{b, b, Table[{-0.02, 0}, {i, b}]}], 
 {b[[1]], "", {-0.02, .04}, Opacity[0]}], 
  Prepend[Transpose[{b, b, Table[{-0.02, 0}, {i, b}]}], 
 {b[[1]], "", {-0.02, .1}, Opacity[0]}]}}]
```

gives

[image: frameticks outside]