# Vertical alignment of FrameTicks Text

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

The text box of a FrameTick/Tick is, by default, vertically centered on the tick mark.

[image: Illustrating alignment of FrameTicks textbox]

Is there a way to adjust the vertical alignment of FrameTick text? Specifically, along the lines of Baseline, Top, etc.

FrameTicksStyle in combination with TextAlignment/Alignment does nothing.

Comment: Related question: [Styling ticks in a plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2969/245)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Pane` as in Szabolcs's answer or `Framed` (with `FrameStyle->None`) with a combination of settings for `BaselinePosition`, `ImageMargins` and `FrameMargins`:

```
  Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{
  {{0, Style[Pane[Style[0.4, FontSize -> 48], 
    BaselinePosition -> (Top -> Bottom), 
    FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 40}}, 
    ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, -40}}], 
   Background -> Green]}}, 
  {{0, Style[Pane[Style[0.4, FontSize -> 48], 
    BaselinePosition -> (Bottom -> Top), 
    FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {40, 0}}, 
    ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {-40, 0}}], 
   Background -> Green]}}}, {None, None}}]
```

you get

[image]

Answer (score 10):

It is also possible to use `AdjustmentBox`, wrapped in `DisplayForm`, to get very fine-grained control over placement of `FrameTicks` text.

The following is based on code I use for my own real-world application.

```
myTickList[min_, max_, seg_, shift_?NumericQ, len_: 0] := 
 Table[{i, 
   DisplayForm[
    AdjustmentBox[Style[i, LineSpacing -> {0, 12}], 
     BoxBaselineShift -> shift]], {len, 0}}, {i, 
   If[Head[seg] === List, Union[{min, max}, seg], 
    Range[min, max, seg]]}]
```

An example of its use. You can see that I've shifted the left-hand frame labels up (with a negative number) and the right-hand ones down (with a positive number).

```
ListLinePlot[Accumulate@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5], 40],
  Frame -> True, GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{myTickList[-4, 4, 1, -2], 
    myTickList[-4, 4, 1, 2]}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you mention your use case, we might be able to give better answers.

I believe that tick marks are places using `Inset` or an equivalent mechanism (`Text` and `Inset` seem to be pretty similar: `Text` also accepts any formatted expression including `Graphics`).  Since I don't seem to be able to get direct access to the `Inset` options, I didn't manage to control the baseline.  The tick symbol is always perfectly centred.

You can use a hack like this instead:

```
Graphics[Circle[],
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {None, {{0, 
     Style[Pane[Style[0, Large, Background -> Green], 
       ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 0}}, ContentPadding -> False], 
      Background -> Red]}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The idea is to add margins to the text, in effect shifting it.  The margins can be added using `Pane`.  In my sample image, the text background is green while the `Pane` background (the margin) is red.