# Customizing the distance of plot frame tick labels to frame

Tags: plotting, spacing

How can I customize the distance between the frame tick labels in a plot and the frame of the plot?

MWE here —nothing special:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 600, 
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 12]]
```

This is the current result:

[image: MWE]

What I want is to add an extra space between the labels in the vertical axis and the vertical axis itself, and the same for the horizontal axis.

Very similar to another question here in this site, but not the same. And I have already tried things like `FrameMargins` without success.

Comment: I suppose you have to make custom ticks with `Pane`.

Comment: related Q/As: [Styling Ticks in a Plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2969/125) and [Vertical Alignment of Ticks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4791/125)

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate because it clearly seems to be, unless I've overlooked an aspect of your question.  I don't find the answers to that question highly satisfying but I am not aware of a better way or I would post it.  Be sure to also read the answers to the questions kguler linked above.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you. You are right.