# Label of Ticks are overlaying

Tags: labeling, ticks

I have a little problem that's driving me crazy.
The problem will be clear from the graphic: the text of the tick labels.
on the Y-Axis are crossing/overlaying.

I tried everything but I found nothing that could fix this problem.
[image: Texts of the Ticks overlay]

For anyone interested, here's the code:

```
 Plot[{1/(5*x)}, {x, 1.8, 6},
 GridLines -> {{{4, Red}, {3.5, Red}}, None},
 AxesLabel -> {L, W/P},
 Ticks -> {None, {{0.049, W/Subscript[P, 2]}, {0.057, 
 W/Subscript[P, 1]}}},
 TicksStyle -> Tiny,
 PlotRange -> {0.02, 0.12},
 AxesOrigin -> {1, 0.02},
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04]]
```

I would be really really glad if someone had a solution for this!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The ticks are close enough in location that you'll either need to tinker with imagesize, aspect ratio, or use a string for the tick ("W/...") using the editing functions to subscript - that will give to much more vertical room.

Comment: try `Ticks -> {None, {{0.049,   Style[Row[{"W / ", Subscript[P, 2]}], 14]}, {0.057,  Style[Row[{"W / ", Subscript[P, 1]}], 15]}}}`?

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to find a way to make the fraction smaller, but there seems no way in Mathematica. I did it your way now.

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping your tick labels in `DisplayForm[AdjustmentBox[...]]`) and setting the [`BoxBaselineShift`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxBaselineShift.html) option will move the labels vertically so they don't clash. Positive numbers for this option move the content down; negative numbers move it up. According to the documentation, the units are x-heights, but for this example, I found I needed numbers larger than 1. This was a bit surprising but might be because Mathematica is taking the x-height from the smaller font size of the fraction, not from normal text.

```
Plot[{1/(5*x)}, {x, 1.8, 6}, 
 GridLines -> {{{4, Red}, {3.5, Red}}, None}, AxesLabel -> {L, W/P}, 
 Ticks -> {None, {{0.049, 
     DisplayForm@
      AdjustmentBox[W/Subscript[P, 2], 
       BoxBaselineShift -> 9]}, {0.057, 
     DisplayForm@
      AdjustmentBox[W/Subscript[P, 1], BoxBaselineShift -> -6]}}}, 
 TicksStyle -> Tiny, PlotRange -> {0.02, 0.12}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {1, 0.02}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Re-using the trick from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4799/125)

```
Plot[{1/(5*x)}, {x, 1.8, 6}, 
 GridLines -> {{{4, Red}, {3.5, Red}}, None}, AxesLabel -> {L, W/P}, 
 Ticks -> {None, {{0.049, 
       Style[Pane[Style[W/Subscript[P, 2], 16], 
       BaselinePosition -> (Bottom -> Top), 
       FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {60, 0}}, 
       ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {-60, 0}}]]}, {0.057, 
     Style[Pane[Style[W/Subscript[P, 1], 16], 
       BaselinePosition -> (Top -> Bottom), 
       FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 60}}, 
       ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, -60}}]]}}}, TicksStyle -> Tiny, 
 PlotRange -> {0.02, 0.12}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0.02}, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Or

```
Plot[{1/(5*x)}, {x, 1.8, 6}, 
 GridLines -> {{{4, Red}, {3.5, Red}}, None}, AxesLabel -> {L, W/P}, 
 Ticks -> {None, {{0.049, 
     Style[Row[{"W / ", Subscript[P, 2]}], 14]}, {0.057, 
     Style[Row[{"W / ", Subscript[P, 1]}], 15]}}}, TicksStyle -> Tiny,
  PlotRange -> {0.02, 0.12}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0.02}, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]