# Can't load LevelScheme package

Tags: packages, levelscheme

I am trying to use Mark Caprio's [LevelScheme package](https://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/) for customizing graphics, but I haven't been able to get *Mathematica* to load the package using `Get` or `Needs`, which return the following errors:

> Get::noopen: Cannot open
>   C:\Users...\Mathematica\Applications\LevelScheme.>>
>
> Needs::nocont: Context LevelScheme` was not created when Needs was
>   evaluated. >>

The package is installed in $UserBaseDirectory under "Applications" alongside a number of other packages that are working fine (Win7, Mma 10.2). What is causing this problem?

---

Same issue observed with *Mathematica* 8:

... downloaded and unzipped package from the [website](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/), saved it in a folder and appended this folder to *Mathematica*'s search path using:

```
AppendTo[$Path, "/Users/alessandromanzotti/Downloads/LevelScheme"]
```

> {"/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links",
>   "/Users/alessandromanzotti/Library/Mathematica/Kernel",
>   "/Users/alessandromanzotti/Library/Mathematica/Autoload", 
>   "/Users/alessandromanzotti/Library/Mathematica/Applications", 
>   "/Library/Mathematica/Kernel", 
>   "/Library/Mathematica/Autoload", 
>   "/Library/Mathematica/Applications", ".", 
>   "/Users/alessandromanzotti", 
>   "/Applications/Mathematica.app/AddOns/Packages",
>   ...
>   "/Users/alessandromanzotti/Work/Software/Mathematica/LevelScheme", \
>   "/Users/alessandromanzotti/Downloads/LevelScheme"}

Everything seems OK

```
SetDirectory["/Users/alessandromanzotti/Downloads/LevelScheme"]; 
FileNames[] ‌
```

> ​{"BlockOptions", "ClipToRectangle"​, "CustomTicks", "doc"​, ".DS_Store",
>   "ForEach"​, "InheritOptions"​, "Kernel" ‌​, "LevelScheme" ‌​, "NamedColors"​}

But I get an error using `Get["LevelScheme`"]`.

Comment: Try putting it in your Program files->Wolfram Reasearch->Mathematica->8.0->AddOns->Packages...and restart Mathematica...in case it doesn't work remove it from there.

Comment: @Blackbird. OP is using OS X. Your suggestion won't work there; _Mathematica_ file structure is different there.

Comment: @m_goldberg: ya I noticed later but I left the comment so that might be helpful to someone in future. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 8):

I faced this same problem. I tried all of the answers mentioned but none of them worked. Finally figured it out.This is what I did:

Firstly after you download the LevelScheme zip file extract it anywhere. In my case(Ubuntu) I extracted it at Desktop.So this is the folder contents after extraction:

[image]

Then you run this to find your Basedirectory

```
  FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

I found mine to be in my home directory under .Mathematica/Applications

Then you simply cut all the folders from above and paste it into the Base directory just found. So in my case after pasting it was like this:
[image]

Then you have to load them one by one in any order keeping LevelScheme last. So like I did this(You may get an error message here but that can be neglected):

```
Get["CustomTicks`"]
Get["BlockOptions`"]
Get["ClipToRectangle`"]
Get["CustomTicks`"]
Get["ForEach`"]
Get["InheritOptions`"]
Get["NamedColors`"]
```

And finally this

```
Get["LevelScheme`"]
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, the zip package actually contains several packages. Btw, you don't have to load the other packages before `LeveScheme`, as they are loaded automatically by `Get["LevelScheme`"]`.

Comment: This works but you need not to load all the packages manually, it is sufficient just to load ``Get["LevelScheme`"]``

Answer (score 6):

Let me make a guess: When you append `"/Users/alessandromanzotti/Downloads/LevelScheme"` to your `$Path`, then it is not possible to load `` LevelScheme` `` because no *sub-directory* contains a package named *LevelScheme*.

Please try the following: Copy the whole `LevelScheme` directory to

```
"/Users/alessandromanzotti/Library/Mathematica/Applications"
```

so that you have a `LevelScheme` subdirectory under `Applications` which contains all its content. Then the package loading should work.

Comment: I have a copy of the whole levelScheme folder in "/Users/alessandromanzotti/Library/Mathematica/Applications" but still, I can not get it... I get the error Get::noopen: Cannot open LevelScheme. if this can help.

Comment: @user1697991: I'm experiencing the same error. `Needs["LevelScheme``", 
 FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications\\LevelScheme"}]]`  Just installed LevelScheme package in Applications directory ... everything should work, but `Get` and `Needs` both return "noopen : Cannot open C\:Users\ ...". This is on Win7, running 10.2 -- maybe it's a permissions issue?

Answer (score 3):

Appending to the `$Path` is not a good idea, because it doesn't change `$Path` permanently. You would have to evaluate the `Append` expression in new session where you planned to use the package. Best to move the package to a standard folder already on $Path. An appropriate folder would be found by evaluating

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

Comment: In my recent (2 minutes ago) case I had to add all the individual directories to \$Path first and then finally the top level LevelScheme directory itself.  If the LevelScheme directory is before the LevelScheme/LevelScheme directory I run into infinite recursion when executing Get["LevelScheme`"].  With $Path in the correct order all seems well.  Documentation is quite misleading here (writing docs is very dull I know ;).