# how to change the distance between tick mark and tick label

Tags: plotting, labeling, ticks

On similar lines as [Is there an option to change the space/distance between tick labels and axes labels for plots?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16802/is-there-an-option-to-change-the-space-distance-between-tick-labels-and-axes-lab) but I would like to reduce the distance between the tick mark and the tick label that appears below it. For eg:

In this figure, I would like to reduce the distance between -2 in the x axis and the tick mark corresponding to it [image]

Edit:

Adding the code that generated this figure:

```
    cutoff = 0.52;
grp1 = {{-4.10855, 1}, {-3.18, 2}, {-2.97477, 3}, {-2.40408, 
    4}, {-2.19854, 5}, {-1.77951, 6}, {-1.76863, 7}, {-1.75573, 
    8}, {-1.71227, 9}, {-1.64262, 10}, {-1.48712, 11}, {-1.42243, 
    12}, {-1.29815, 13}, {-1.18774, 14}, {-1.03156, 15}, {-0.978796, 
    16}, {-0.971106, 17}, {-0.922292, 18}, {-0.862833, 
    19}, {-0.807821, 20}, {-0.775937, 21}, {-0.750941, 
    22}, {-0.737334, 23}, {-0.715059, 24}, {-0.712102, 
    25}, {-0.693181, 26}, {-0.69129, 27}, {-0.674491, 28}, {-0.644356,
     29}, {-0.620938, 30}, {-0.59347, 31}, {-0.589228, 
    32}, {-0.581852, 33}, {-0.580016, 34}, {-0.56826, 35}, {-0.566551,
     36}, {-0.561733, 37}, {-0.55583, 38}, {-0.551104, 
    39}, {-0.549835, 40}, {-0.535232, 41}, {-0.53486, 42}, {-0.533395,
     43}, {-0.523652, 44}, {-0.520547, 45}, {-0.508359, 
    46}, {-0.506626, 47}, {-0.491825, 48}, {-0.490019, 49}, {-0.477, 
    50}, {-0.473228, 51}, {-0.470723, 52}, {-0.470415, 
    53}, {-0.454857, 54}, {-0.454278, 55}, {-0.452099, 
    56}, {-0.421126, 57}, {-0.41768, 58}, {-0.415444, 59}, {-0.402139,
     60}, {-0.387403, 61}, {-0.380952, 62}, {-0.374082, 
    63}, {-0.373277, 64}, {-0.370055, 65}, {-0.364634, 
    66}, {-0.361553, 67}, {-0.361208, 68}, {-0.360869, 69}, {-0.34248,
     70}, {-0.340748, 71}, {-0.33172, 72}, {-0.330729, 
    73}, {-0.311965, 74}, {-0.310625, 75}, {-0.304104, 
    76}, {-0.302831, 77}, {-0.302533, 78}, {-0.29397, 79}, {-0.291521,
     80}, {-0.289982, 81}, {-0.27621, 82}, {-0.264455, 
    83}, {-0.256689, 84}, {-0.250929, 85}, {-0.246889, 
    86}, {-0.228836, 87}, {-0.22671, 88}, {-0.202538, 89}, {-0.196612,
     90}, {-0.187845, 91}, {-0.187817, 92}, {-0.179211, 
    93}, {-0.173247, 94}, {-0.165728, 95}, {-0.163806, 
    96}, {-0.153261, 97}, {-0.132747, 98}, {-0.122831, 
    99}, {-0.117507, 100}, {-0.113069, 101}, {-0.102309, 
    102}, {-0.0976552, 103}, {-0.0951561, 104}, {-0.0894875, 
    105}, {-0.0876338, 106}, {-0.087434, 107}, {-0.0845464, 
    108}, {-0.0757364, 109}, {-0.0635816, 110}, {-0.0621387, 
    111}, {-0.0580457, 112}, {-0.0558367, 113}, {-0.0529842, 
    114}, {-0.0478612, 115}, {-0.0444608, 116}, {-0.0410887, 
    117}, {-0.0398071, 118}, {-0.0322021, 119}, {-0.0200628, 
    120}, {-0.0182955, 121}, {-0.0144614, 122}, {-0.0138035, 
    123}, {-0.00716598, 124}, {0., 125}, {0.0103846, 126}, {0.0205011,
     127}, {0.0341349, 128}, {0.059813, 129}, {0.0954803, 
    130}, {0.123192, 131}, {0.123591, 132}, {0.147797, 
    133}, {0.166342, 134}, {0.16952, 135}, {0.186956, 136}, {0.206183,
     137}, {0.210853, 138}, {0.260639, 139}, {0.287231, 
    140}, {0.30835, 141}, {0.314636, 142}, {0.329798, 143}, {0.334356,
     144}, {0.36056, 145}, {0.383386, 146}, {0.45576, 147}, {0.457104,
     148}, {0.46041, 149}, {0.482364, 150}};

grp2 = {{0.559846, 151}, {0.603893, 152}, {0.692402, 153}, {0.736425, 
    154}, {0.742579, 155}, {0.750076, 156}, {0.879458, 
    157}, {0.967285, 158}, {0.988934, 159}, {1.04353, 160}, {1.06206, 
    161}, {1.12605, 162}, {1.13691, 163}, {1.14313, 164}, {1.22551, 
    165}, {1.24425, 166}, {1.32567, 167}, {1.35547, 168}, {1.3873, 
    169}, {1.46251, 170}, {1.48027, 171}, {1.48587, 172}, {1.50248, 
    173}, {1.50557, 174}, {1.52349, 175}, {1.52676, 176}, {1.61266, 
    177}, {1.6306, 178}, {1.71358, 179}, {1.73984, 180}, {1.79301, 
    181}, {1.81201, 182}, {1.86031, 183}, {1.90378, 184}, {1.91104, 
    185}, {1.932, 186}, {1.94978, 187}, {1.96444, 188}, {1.97321, 
    189}, {1.98785, 190}, {1.99161, 191}, {2.02637, 192}, {2.04347, 
    193}, {2.05299, 194}, {2.07511, 195}, {2.08866, 196}, {2.17186, 
    197}, {2.19635, 198}, {2.2132, 199}, {2.22343, 200}, {2.22452, 
    201}, {2.24434, 202}, {2.25782, 203}, {2.2627, 204}, {2.27745, 
    205}, {2.46167, 206}, {2.48096, 207}, {2.54055, 208}, {2.64996, 
    209}, {2.65934, 210}, {2.73535, 211}, {2.78724, 212}, {2.79484, 
    213}, {2.79819, 214}, {2.88538, 215}, {2.89362, 216}, {2.96651, 
    217}, {3.00729, 218}, {3.07063, 219}, {3.11961, 220}, {3.19508, 
    221}, {3.2295, 222}, {3.23329, 223}, {3.27631, 224}, {3.3876, 
    225}, {3.41121, 226}, {3.46174, 227}, {3.61129, 228}, {3.61579, 
    229}, {3.64525, 230}, {3.77605, 231}, {3.91162, 232}, {3.91579, 
    233}, {3.9266, 234}, {4.12641, 235}, {4.15509, 236}, {4.21151, 
    237}, {4.25269, 238}, {4.41959, 239}, {4.4295, 240}, {4.45912, 
    241}, {4.70492, 242}, {4.72227, 243}, {4.93772, 244}, {5.7519, 
    245}, {5.92314, 246}, {6.20269, 247}, {6.23834, 248}, {7.70686, 
    249}};

Show[ListPlot[{grp1, grp2}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Column[{Style["x", FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
      Style["y", FontFamily -> "Courier"]}, Center], "(b) z", None, 
    None, None}, AspectRatio -> 1.8, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, PointSize[0.01]}, {Red, PointSize[0.01]}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{-2, -2, {0, 0.03}}, {0, 0, {0, 0.03}}, {cutoff, 
      "   " <> ToString[N[Round[cutoff, 10^-1]]], {0, 0.03}}, {2, 
      2, {0, 0.03}}, {4, 4, {0, 0.03}}, {6, 6, {0, 0.03}}}, {{1, 
      1, {0, 0.03}}, {50, 50, {0, 0.03}}, {100, 100, {0, 0.03}}, {150,
       150, {0, 0.03}}, {200, 200, {0, 0.03}}}, None, None}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> {211, 335}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{50, 0}, {50, 0}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {1, 250}}], 
 Graphics[{Dashed, Black, Line[{{cutoff, 1}, {cutoff, 249}}]}]]
```

Comment: The gap seems much bigger than default so we really need the code that generated that plot to give the best answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the ticks are `FrameTicks`, I'll generate an example plot with a frame and then replace its ticks using `Framed` with negative `FrameMargins` in the vertical directions:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True];

With[{verticalShrink = 5},
 Show[p, FrameTicks -> (Map[# /. ({x_, xL_, dir___} :> {x, 
          Framed[xL, FrameStyle -> None, 
           FrameMargins -> {{Automatic, 
              Automatic}, {-1, -1} verticalShrink}], dir}) &, 
     FrameTicks /. First[AbsoluteOptions[p, FrameTicks]], {2}])]
 ]
```

[image: frame]

Or with the frame labels similar to your example:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"\*GridBox[{
{x},
{y}
}]", "\!\(\*FormBox[\(b(z)\),
TraditionalForm]\)"}];

With[{verticalShrink = 5},
 Show[p, FrameTicks -> (Map[# /. ({x_, xL_, dir___} :> {x, 
          Framed[xL, FrameStyle -> None, 
           FrameMargins -> {{Automatic, 
              Automatic}, {-1, -1} verticalShrink}], dir}) &, 
     FrameTicks /. First[AbsoluteOptions[p, FrameTicks]], {2}])]
 ]
```

[image: frame2]

Since you didn't provide the code that produced your example, I can only add that the specific tick style (pointing outward) can be created the usual way in the plot `p`, and then you use the `With` block on the desired plot `p`.

I used a quick-and dirty shrinking trick here: *indiscriminately* make the vertical frame margins negative in both top and bottom directions, so that I don't have to treat the vertical and horizontal ticks separately (the vertical alignment of the vertical ticks labels stays centered). But this (crude) top/bottom balanced approach means the shrinkage of vertical spacing is limited, and you can't make the tick labels touch the axis.

If you want to have more control, you'll need to make the replacement of tick labels by `Framed` tick labels act only on the horizontal bottom labels. The `FrameMargins` at top and bottom then should be chosen unequal. I can add that if it's necessary. See also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2999/245).

Comment: That helps. I did play around with the frame margin etc to get what I want. I was wondering if there is any way to determine what is the space left outside of the frame margin by default. When combining plots, despite adjusting imagesize, imagepadding etc, the difference in the distance between tick labels and tick marks were unequal in my figure. Anyways, for now, I decreased the distance of frame margin in one and increased in the other to make them equal.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the labels seem to stay close to the ticks, whatever length you give them:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[Sort@RandomReal[300, {50}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> 
   {
    Table[{x, ToString[x], {0, n}}, {x, 0, 50, 5}],
    Table[{x, ToString[x], {0, n}}, {x, 0, 300, 25}]
    }
  ], 
 {n, -0.02, 0.02, 0.005}]
```

[image: ticks]