# Distance between axes and tick labels

Tags: plotting, labeling, histograms, style

A similar question has been axed before in the context of a Framed plot: see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29505/how-to-change-the-distance-between-tick-mark-and-tick-label). My plot is unframed so I wasn't able to apply the answer to the other question.

I create a histogram with the code below. The tick labels end up too tight to the axes themselves. How to make them be further way from the axes?

```
hg = Histogram[{10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 60, 
60}, {0, 60, 10}, "Count",
   PlotRange -> {{5, 65}, Automatic},
   BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "cmr12", FontSize -> 100],
   Ticks -> {Range[0, 80, 10], Automatic},
   TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 100, FontFamily -> "cmr12"],
   Axes -> {True, True},
   GridLines -> {None, Automatic},
   GridLinesStyle -> Black,
   ChartStyle ->  Directive[LightGray, EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[4]]],
   AspectRatio -> .4,
   ImageSize -> {3000, 1080}];
Magnify[hg, .25]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Framed` on the tick labels and control the margins around the labels with the option `FrameMargins`:

```
Ticks -> {{#, Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 1, FrameStyle -> None]} & /@ Range[0, 80, 10], 
  {#, Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 1, FrameStyle -> None]} & /@ Range[0, 12, 2]}
```

[image]

You can set different margins for the four sides of the label:

```
Ticks -> {{#, Framed[#, FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, Scaled[.05]}}, 
      FrameStyle -> None]} & /@ Range[0, 80, 10], 
    {#, Framed[#, FrameMargins -> {{0, Scaled[.05]}, {0, 0}}, 
      FrameStyle -> None]} & /@ Range[0, 12, 2]}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Pane[#, FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, Scaled[.05]}}]` instead of `Framed[..]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try also this:

```
Manipulate[
 lab1 = Join[{{0, 0, n, Directive[White]}}, Range[10, 80, 10]];
 lab2 = Transpose[{Range[0, 12, 2], 
    Row[{#, Spacer[m]}] & /@ ToString /@ Range[0, 12, 2]}];
 hg = Histogram[{10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
    30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 60, 
    60}, {0, 60, 10}, "Count", PlotRange -> {{5, 65}, Automatic}, 
   BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "cmr12", FontSize -> 100], 
   Ticks -> {lab1, lab2}, 
   TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 100, FontFamily -> "cmr12"], 
   Axes -> {True, True}, GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Black, 
   ChartStyle -> Directive[LightGray, EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[4]]],
    AspectRatio -> .4, ImageSize -> {3000, 1080}];
 Magnify[hg, .25], {n, 0.01, 0.3}, {m, 10, 30}]
```

[image]

and play with the sliders to position the ticks labels where you need them.

Have fun!