# Why does the space between ticks and frame on x and y axes is different?

Tags: plotting, ticks

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1,
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 26}]
```

[image]

How can I make space the same?

Comment: Try to play with the value of the option `AspectRatio`. I guess the intervals  will be equal at the value 0.7 to 0.8.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XvO8.png) is the y-tick measurement rotated and colored green and it fits perfectly inside the x-tick box. I would say it is an illusion.

Comment: @Syed what I meant is the space between ticks and frame?! I don't understand how that can be an illusion, or did u mean something else?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, it seems that space is independent of `AspectRatio`

Comment: Similar to [29505](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29505/how-to-change-the-distance-between-tick-mark-and-tick-label).

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but rather an explanation what the cause of the problem is and why I think it can be regarded as a bug in styling of text.

As can be seen on the image bellow after adding `Background -> Red` we can see that spacing above and bellow of tick labels are added in the plot however when the same style is used on ordinary text/string the spacing above and below are `0` so therefore I take it as a bug.

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 1,
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 20, 
   Background -> Red}]

Style["-1.0", {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 20, 
  Background -> Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: The extra vertical space is from the internal `Inset`, which your second example does not include.  Here is a more accurate example of what is going on...  ``Graphics[{Style[Inset@"-1.0", {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 20, Background -> Red}]}]``  It could be a bug, it might not.  Hard for me to say without spending more time researching this.